# Как получить определённые данные из строки?

Tags: javascript, json, строки

Как можно получить данные `questId`, `value`, `completed`, тут они получается выведутся два раза.
Пытался строку преобразовать в json, но данные не получилось достать

```json
[{
  "id": "b296573d-2420-4f0d-8ae3-b7e11ab9b54a",
  "spaceId": "test",
  "userId": "3298d30d-2eae-4719-bec8-15f262d707a6",
  "gameId": "test:game:test",
  "weekId": "64388df1-7d12-455d-afd2-0f104251d8a4",
  "questId": "40fbf3ce-928a-46e3-8a66-125e6ed08fb4",
  "value": "10",
  "completed": true,
  "createdAt": "2022-02-04T12:21:55.448Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-02-04T12:21:55.448Z"
}, {
  "id": "10b82fe7-a9e0-4049-81de-346a5cf15d99",
  "spaceId": "test",
  "userId": "3298d30d-2eae-4719-bec8-15f262d707a6",
  "gameId": "test:game:test",
  "weekId": "64388df1-7d12-455d-afd2-0f104251d8a4",
  "questId": "fa7e7f69-5fbd-4a1f-b531-abb7eb62a2b5",
  "value": "10",
  "completed": true,
  "createdAt": "2022-02-04T12:39:09.048Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-02-04T12:39:09.048Z"
}]
```

Comment: что значит 'не получилось достать'? а как пытались? пример?

Comment: вот так пытался console.log(r.id);
console.log(r[0].id);

Comment: а где эе тут преобразование в json?

Comment: изначально эти данные приходят с сервера в виде строки

Comment: `console.log(r[0].id);` --- это верный вариант, если сделать изначально преобразование из строки

Comment: @Ivan912 вы через ajax их получаете?

Comment: да через ajax, приходит вот такая строка

Comment: скажите в параметрах `dataType: "json"` и сразу получите массив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const json = "[{\n  \"id\": \"b296573d-2420-4f0d-8ae3-b7e11ab9b54a\",\n  \"spaceId\": \"test\",\n  \"userId\": \"3298d30d-2eae-4719-bec8-15f262d707a6\",\n  \"gameId\": \"test:game:test\",\n  \"weekId\": \"64388df1-7d12-455d-afd2-0f104251d8a4\",\n  \"questId\": \"40fbf3ce-928a-46e3-8a66-125e6ed08fb4\",\n  \"value\": \"10\",\n  \"completed\": true,\n  \"createdAt\": \"2022-02-04T12:21:55.448Z\",\n  \"updatedAt\": \"2022-02-04T12:21:55.448Z\"\n}, {\n  \"id\": \"10b82fe7-a9e0-4049-81de-346a5cf15d99\",\n  \"spaceId\": \"test\",\n  \"userId\": \"3298d30d-2eae-4719-bec8-15f262d707a6\",\n  \"gameId\": \"test:game:test\",\n  \"weekId\": \"64388df1-7d12-455d-afd2-0f104251d8a4\",\n  \"questId\": \"fa7e7f69-5fbd-4a1f-b531-abb7eb62a2b5\",\n  \"value\": \"10\",\n  \"completed\": true,\n  \"createdAt\": \"2022-02-04T12:39:09.048Z\",\n  \"updatedAt\": \"2022-02-04T12:39:09.048Z\"\n}]";

const data = JSON.parse(json);
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i].questId);
  console.log(data[i].vaxqlue);
  console.log(data[i].completed);
}
```

Comment: как вы преобразовали строку, что там появились /n?

Comment: @Ivan912 Ну как) Скопировал Ваш код из вопроса, вставил на сайт Add Slashes online, он все это экранировал и заодно остальные символы, чтобы получилась просто строка. Так перенос строки стал его символом - /n

Comment: спасибо большое